# Creating 3D Hologram of Human Anatomy from 2D Image

Tags: extrude, svg

I'm a beginner to Blender, and I've been struggling to create a 3D model of a human anatomy hologram from a 2D image. I've tried converting the image to an SVG and then editing & extruding it in Blender. The problem is that I get a low-quality render when I extrude the image. I've also tried using the displace modifier, but that didn't work either. Attached below is the image I'm trying to model.

[image: human anatomy hologram]

Comment: Hello, you'd better find a 3D model of a human body